# mysql left join with multiple where columns

Tags: mysql

I have a customer table and an address table. Each customer can have multiple entries in the address table, but only one of those entries can be marked as 'primary'. I've put together the query to pull up the customer and their primary address as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM customers LEFT JOIN addresses  
         ON customers.cust_id = addresses.cust_id 
WHERE customers.status = 1 AND addresses.primary = 1
```

I've found a flaw in that if the customer has not yet added an address to their account, they will not appear because there is no 'primary' address.

What's the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM      customers 
LEFT JOIN addresses 
ON        customers.cust_id = addresses.cust_id
AND       1                 = addresses.primary 
WHERE     customers.status = 1
```

Comment: brilliant. didn't realise you could use an AND in a JOIN like that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use any expression there; functions, even subqueries. However, for best performance, stick to column comparisons and/or constants. The query above will work fine; probably better or just as good as the `OR` construct suggested by the others. However, I feel this way of stating it is cleaner, more clear, and less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the query to `AND (addresses.primary = 1 OR addresses.primary IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the left side data when there is no address.
In the example below I use the primary field, but any field of the addesses table
is null in a left join clause when there is no matching key.

```
SELECT * FROM customers LEFT JOIN addresses   
         ON customers.cust_id = addresses.cust_id  
WHERE    customers.status = 1 AND 
         (addresses.primary = 1 OR addresses.primary IS Null)
```